# How do I get text side by side in HTML inside div?

Tags: html, css

How do I get the "basic"-link text over the second image and these two images + the text centered? 
It looks like my post is mostly code, i will add more details to my question.

Thanks!

Here is the JSfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/fvg4c0j0/

```
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
  <body>
 <div id="container"><!---container--->
   <div id="header">
   <h1>JORDAS</h1>

  </div><!--header-->

  <div id="nav">
 <a href="index.html">Etusivu</a> <br>
  <a href="page1.html">Teltat</a><br>
 <a href="page2.html">Palvelut</a><br>
 <a href="page3.html">Yhteistiedot</a><br>
 </div>

<div id="section">
 <a href="page2.html"><h1>Pro</h1></a>
  <a href="page2.html"><h1>Basic</h1></a>

      <div class="main_block">

  <div class="inner_block">
     <img src=Grafik/talt.png>
   </div>



  <div class="inner_block">
    <img src=Grafik/talt.png >
    </div>    

 </div><!--mainblock-->
  </div>

     <div id="footer">
        <h3>POP-UP TELTTOJEN YKKÖNEN </h3>
          </div><!--footer-->
       </div> <!--container-->
        </body>
```

And here is the css

```
 <style>

 body{margin:0;
padding:0;
   }
  #header {
background-color:#ff6600;
color:white;
text-align:left;
padding:2px;
  }

 #nav {
line-height:30px;
background-color:#fff000;
height:350px;
width:120px;
float:left;
padding:5px;

 }
    #section {
     width:350px;
    float:left;
     padding:10px;
   }
   #footer {
background-color:#737373;
color:white;
clear:both;
text-align:center;


     }
   #container {
margin:auto;
width:900px;
text-align:left;
overflow: hidden;

   }
  .inner_block {
   display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 150px;
    height:200px;


  }

  img {
   width: 150px;
    }
    #basic {
    float:right;

   }
  </style>
```

Comment: To clarify, I'd like the link to be above the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="main_block">

    <div class="inner_block">
        <a href="page2.html"><h1>Pro</h1></a>
        <img src=Grafik/talt.png>
    </div>

    <div class="inner_block">
        <a href="page2.html"><h1>Basic</h1></a>
        <img src=Grafik/talt.png >
    </div>    

</div><!--mainblock-->
```

css :

```
.main_block{
  text-align:center;
  width:750px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you clarify, do you want the text above the image? or sitting on the image?

Okay cool what I would do if I were you is this for the html and then

```
<div class='inner'>
    <div class='inner-link'>
        <a href='#'>Basic</a>
    </div>
    <div class='inner-image'>
      <img src='x'>
    </div>
</div>
```

This for the css

```
inner{
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
}
inner-link{
  width:100%;
  text-align:center
}
```